# Coluna para gravar data e hora da alteração SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, firebird

Estou migrando um banco de dados de `Firebird` para `Sql Server` e hoje, no `Firebird` tenho algumas triggers no `Before Insert/Update` que gravam o `TimeStamp` da inserção/alteração e o usuário logado.

Existe alguma forma de eu fazer isso no `Sql Server` sem ser utilizando triggers do tipo `Instead Of`?

Comment: Pode demostrar como você faz isso no firebird?

Comment: No firebird é bem simples isso, em uma trigger do tipo before Insert/Update, só colocar um:
new.DATAHORA = current_timestamp;
new.USUARIO = current_user;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim. Para inserções, na declaração da sua tabela, use o seguinte:

```
CREATE TABLE TABELA (
    ...
    DATA_CRIACAO DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ...
);
```

Para atualização vai ter que ser por *trigger*:

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.UltimaModificacaoTabela
ON dbo.Tabela
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT UPDATE(ULTIMA_MODIFICACAO) -- Evitar recursão na coluna
    BEGIN
        UPDATE t
            SET t.ULTIMA_MODIFICACAO = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            FROM dbo.Tabela AS t
            INNER JOIN inserted AS i 
            ON t.ID = i.ID;
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda :)